# volt : pass variable to include from parent template

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I am **beginner** with volt ,

I have a template that use a **partials**
like this

**main.volt**

```
<div>
  hello to 
  {{ partial("partials/tst",["name":"kevin"]) }}
</div>
```

and I use that variable like this
**partial/tst.volt**

```
<b>
{{name}}
</b>
```

but I get an error like this

```
Undefined variable
```

how can I **fix** this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code are ok, I test it and get correct name in the view:

[image: Index file capture]

I have the partial like you:

[image: Partial code capture]

And finally I get this in my view:
[image: view result]